# How can I create a UITableViewCell with subview of set height using autolayout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, ios-autolayout

I have a table view cell (yellow) with one subview (red):
[image]

The subview should have a fixed height of 100. And should have a border of 5 top, and 5 bottom to the cell.

The table row needs to be dynamic:

```
table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
table.estimatedRowHeight = 110
```

**What I have tried**: I set the height of the subview to 100, and set the top and bottom to 5 away from the superview. But Interface Builder complains that either Y position or height constraints are missing.

All I want to accomplish is this. 5 at top. 5 at bottom. redview = 100.
How can I resolve this?
[image]

**EDIT**: Here is the sample file -> https://github.com/patchthecode/Autolayout

Comment: You can't have _both_ a fixed height and spacing from a variably-sized superview. Something's gotta give.

Comment: What is the error message in the storyboard?

Comment: It says needs constraints for Y position or height.

Comment: Hi, then how is it possible i can accomplish this? To have the Redview to have a fixed height of 100, and for it to be 5 away from the top and bottom like in the image? A design like this is very simple i thought... but i'm los ton how to do it

Comment: Since the view's height will be set at runtime, you just need to satisfy Interface Builder. A constraint for the cell that's not installed should do it, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Adding center y align to the super view(cell) will satisfy the interface builder.